# Unmet dependencies on libc6 and libstdc++ when installing mssq-tools

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am trying to install Microsoft SQL tools and am hitting an error on the dependencies.  The same error occurs when using apt-get.  As you can see, aptitude has no way to resolve the problem other than not installing mssq-tools.

I am pretty unexperienced in diagnosing package issues and would greatly appreciate your help in understanding what is going on here.

```
$> sudo aptitude install mssql-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mssql-tools{b}
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 235 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,263 kB of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mssql-tools : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.21) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.12 is installed and it is kept back.
               Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.6.3-1ubuntu5 is installed.
               Depends: libgss3 but it is not going to be installed.
               Depends: msodbcsql (>= 13.0.0.0) but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     mssql-tools [Not Installed]
```

My version of Ubuntu is below:

```
$> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using? are you sure it is supported?

Comment: Your Ubuntu version might be too old. I have 16.04 and e.g. libstdc++6 is 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4

Comment: Yes, @steeldriver and user205301, you are correct.  I just checked the requirements and it is only supported on 16.04.  Do you recommend I delete this question or would one of you like to create an answer stating that it is unsupported on my Ubuntu version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: This is rather short - please explain, how and where you found that information.

Comment: This page states that Ubuntu 16.04 is needed for mysql-tools: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup